# Info option is missing from the dropdown on tag pages

Tags: bug, mobile-web, tags-page

When a tag page is visited from mobile site, **info** option is missing from the dropdown.

**Mobile site:**

[image]

**Full site:**

> [image]

Comment: Not a bug, some pages simply have no mobile version.